# Data Sheet view is not highlighting errors when missing the required filed

Tags: list-view, custom-list, view, quick-edit, error-handling

There are required columns in my list and when I try to edit the list via 'quick edit' option by selecting it from the ribbon and if I miss any required field it highlights with the errors for missing the required columns in red exclamation mark.

Contrary, when I tried to enter multiple values in the datasheet view and miss any values it doesn't highlight any errors for missing the required columns.

We need datasheet view so that multiple people can enter values in the list in bulk and it would be convenient for them if default view of a list is a datasheet view.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using?? Can you add a screenshot ??

Comment: I am using SharePoint online